# Android Studio - device monitor tool is just a blank window

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have a problem with android studio's device monitor tool. When I start the tool I just got this:

[image: device monitor tool]

I can't click anything. It's just a blank view which looks broken. When I first run the tool I got this popuplar error which is caused by the problem that the terminal is using a different java verison then android studio itself. I fixed this problem by installing a new JDK. This is the current version printed out from terminal:

```
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

I also tried to launch the tool with the terminal via `sudo ./monitor` in the tools folder in android's sdk directory. I got the same blank view.

Next I thought maybe something is wrong with the `adb commands` in terminal. But those are also working when using terminal.

I thought I saw once a error like `DDMS preferences could not be loaded` when launching the tool via terminal. But the error never appeared again after that. But to be sure I read on stackoverflow that the solution for this is to reinstall the tools via android studio or downloading it manually and replace the folder. So I also did this.

As you can see I tried my best to solve the weird behaviour but I just don't know what happend here cause I don't get any errors. Unfortunately this tool looks very powerful to me in aspect of seeing what happend actually on the device when developing an android app.

So does someone has a similar problem or can help me here? Maby a hint where I can find a log or something?

Comment: Same problem, did you get a solution ?

Comment: Nope. Still have the problem :/

Comment: same here... but anyway this tool is deprecated and will be removed in android studio 3.2

Comment: Why they want to remove this tool? It seems very helpful what I read so far. For example I had to write a script by myself which is only functionality is to extract the realm database from Android. This tool has this kind of functionality included..

Comment: Ive got same issue, Looking for an android monitor as I am developing in vscode not Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by downgrade JDK to 1.8.0_151.
here is my environment

```
on Mac OS 11.6

java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

another thing is, if you have more than one JDK, please make sure that the monitor can find the version 1.8.151.